# Showing that the homomorphism $K[X] \to K^K, p \mapsto \underline p$ is not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, ring-homomorphism

This is Exercise 16 from page page 83 of *Analysis I* from Amann and Escher.

**Exercise:**

> [image]

I have some further context at the bottom of this post.

**My attempt:**

I don't understand the hint at all. On an earlier page he defines $\mathbb F_2 := \big( \{ 0, 1 \}, +, \cdot \big)$. I checked the index and I don't see a definition of $\mathbb F_2 [X]$. Is it a polynomial field with two elements? Or a polynomial field containing only polynomials of order 2? I'm not sure the latter makes sense, because it wouldn't be closed under multiplication.

I understand that to prove injectivity, you want to show that two outputs being equal implies the inputs are equal, or equivalently that different inputs implies different outputs. But the hint is an element of the domain, right?

Another question I have is why the proof of Remark 8.14 (c) doesn't apply in the case of this exercise. (The Remark and context are at the bottom of this post.) A field is just a nice ring, and the proof below applies to a nontrivial finite ring, which as far as I can tell is applicable to the exercise. Can't I just point to that proof given by the book and be done with it?

I appreciate any help.

**Context:**

> [image]

Comment: For $p(X) = X^2-X \in \mathbb F_2[X],$ we can show by computing $p(0) = 0 = p(1)$ that $\underline{p} = 0$.  That's the point of the hint.

Comment: I am still lost in the notation. Trying to explain to myself: $p := X^2 - X \in \mathbb F_2 [X]$ is a function from the natural numbers into $\mathbb F_2$ as described in my post. It can be thought of as a sequence $(0, -1, 1, 0, \dots)$ although I don't know how to justify the $-1$ because I don't know what $-1$ is in the field. In this field $-1 = 1$, right? I think what you are trying to show me is that this function, when fed through the homomorphism, results in a function that sends every element to $0$.

Comment: I think we're trying to show this function sends two different inputs to the same output, but I don't see how we've done that. Need to think more.

Comment: There is an error in the excerpt you quote. It is false that $R[X]=R^{\mathbb{N}}$ (this is *never* true, unless $R=\{0\}$). While it is true that $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable, $R[X]$ is not. However, $R[X]$ is still countably infinite, so the rest of the argument does work.
And yes, proposition 8.14(c) does apply, so you could quote that and be done. I think the idea is to construct an explicit counter-example to injectivity in case $K$ is a finite field, just like the hint suggests.
Also, whenever $R$ is a ring, $R[X]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $R$.

Comment: To supplement Thorgott's comment, as additive groups, we have canonical isomorphisms $$R[[X]] = \prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}R := R^\mathbb{N} \\ R[X] = \bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}R \subsetneq R^\mathbb{N}$$ It looks like the author confused these two, since they [based on your previous question] defined polynomials as special types of formal power series.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. I'm going to have to chew on this for a while.